# How can to get forgotten username on Debian?

Tags: debian, user-accounts, login, password-recovery, username

I have a Debian desktop. On last time, I had updated/upgraded. Now I cannot login (maybe I forgotten username). I cannot login to root too. It seems that we cannot login with root (we just can switch to root). I can make sure about the password. How can I retrieve the username? Thanks!
(There are no GUI to login here after update, just a black screen asking for username/password)

Comment: Boot to live OS and go to the drive of Debian. Look through the file system until your find a folder containing the different users and their home directory.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when I have a live OS (in my usb).

Answer (score 0):

First go to Grub boot menu. (If you can't see it, press "ESC" key)
Press '**e**' to get edit option for Grub

Go to Kernel option line and again press "**e**"

Remove `quiet splash` and add `init=/bin/bash` press Enter and then "**b**" to boot

Then you will get a bash command prompt, type

```
mount -o remount,rw / mount -o remount,rw /proc
```

To change your password, type

```
passwd
```

Enter your new password and reboot using `sync`
[This site](http://linuxconfig.org/recover-reset-forgotten-linux-root-password)Contains more details. If these options are not working, please refer this site.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this without error but the problem was not resolved. I still cannot login. After reboot to a bash command prompt, I can see my usrename when `cat /etc/passwd`. I also changed/updated the password for both the user and root.

Comment: Did you follow alternative methods available in that site? I gave you a common method. That site explains some other methods.

Comment: Yes, I did as your link to add `init=/bin/bash` then I can enter to a bash shell. In this, I run commands to see file /etc/passwd and to update the password